# Cross-compiling Snap7 for MIPS with OpenWrt as OS

Tags: linux, cross-platform, mips, cross-compiling, openwrt

Currently i'm working on a project to log data out of a Siemens PLC. To achieve this i'm using Snap7. Snap7 (http://snap7.sourceforge.net/) is a communication library.

I've managed to get it work on my linux desktop but when i try to cross-compile the snap7 library i get some errors

The error is generated when linking all of the object files.

```
g++ -shared -fPIC -o ../bin/mips-openwrt-linux-g++/libsnap7.so @"filelist.txt" -L.  -lpthread -lrt  -O3
/usr/bin/ld: ../temp/mips-openwrt-linux/sys_snap_msgsock.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 8)
./temp/mips-openwrt-linux/sys_snap_msgsock.o: could not read symbols: File in wrong format
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [../bin/mips-openwrt-linux-g++/libsnap7.so] Error 1
```

If i'm correct i think it's using the wrong linker, it should use the linker of the toolchain located at: openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mips_34kc_gcc-4.8-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/bin/

I've also tried to compile the software with mips-openwrt-linux-g++.
Now another error is given:

```
mips-openwrt-linux-g++ -shared -fPIC -o ../bin/mips-openwrt-linux-g++/libsnap7.so @"filelist.txt" -L.  -lpthread -lrt  -O3
openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mips_34kc_gcc-4.8-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/lib/gcc/mips-openwrt-linux-uclibc/4.8.3/../../../../mips-openwrt-linux-uclibc/bin/ld: ../temp/mips-openwrt-linux/sys_snap_msgsock.o: relocation R_MIPS_26 against `close' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
../temp/mips-openwrt-linux/sys_snap_msgsock.o: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [../bin/mips-openwrt-linux-g++/libsnap7.so] Error 1
```

I hope someone is familiar with this error and can help me out.

Thanks in advance.

edit1:
There are some pre-compiled binaries. In the makefiles i changed the CC to my g++ directory. There is no LD flag so i cannot set my linker over there.

Answer (score 0):

Can you cross compile and run a "hello world" program?

What is the output of `file ../temp/mips-openwrt-linux/sys_snap_msgsock.o`?

Comment: Hello markgz, thanks for answering. after some hours i achieved cross-compiling it. the linker was set wrong. LinkerName and SharedObjectLinkerName need to reference to the correct g++ linker. Also, when you cross-compile MIPS you will achieve a "Bus Error". Possibly a segmentation fault cause of writing in unaccessable memory. Solution is to change the swap functions in snap_sysutils.cpp. Just return the value without bit swapping.